# Highstock / Highchart. type area. How to make captions over areas?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to make this: i.stack.imgur.com/eeUco.png

```
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
        type: 'area',
        zoomType: 'xy'
        },

    title : {
            text : 'test'
        },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            stacking: 'normal',     
            connectNulls: true
              }
       },
        series: Series
    });
```

And secondly(optionally) could somebody show me how to improve overlaps, see, second & third?

http://jsfiddle.net/insolublegenome/7rtJK/4/

Comment: I see in the screenshot the same chart as in your jsfiddle, so what should be changed, what is your question?

Comment: How to make captions atop areas. As you can see, there is no captions in my jsfiddle example, but in the picture.

Comment: You need to use the renderer which allows to add custom text http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text

Comment: There is zoom, in my highstock, labels should automatically applied to areas. Looks like, this method - Renderer.text doesn't support it, except I'll tangle every events complitelly.

Comment: You need to update x/y coordinates of rendererd object

Comment: Is there default option? I'm thinking that recalculation of x/y every zoom in/out with Renderer.text is a too complex code injection.

Comment: It is not built-in, but is not complex injection, you need to upated only coordaintes, by attr() function on the SVG object.

Comment: Could you share little example with 3-4 areas and zoom for me http://jsfiddle.net/insolublegenome/7rtJK/4/ ?